# Font rendering: has something changed from 16.04 to 18.04?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, fonts

And, if the answer is yes, how can I revert back to how it was before?

I'm asking this because I recently switched to a fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04, and I found that text is rendered slightly differently than before. This leads to strange formatting of some ODT files. I have the same fonts installed on both systems (16.04 and 18.04), and I even tried some live images (Ubuntu 16.04.5, Ubuntu 18.04, Lubuntu 18.04, Lubuntu 18.10), but the result is still the same: text is correctly rendered only on 16.04 (even on the live distribution without the proper font installed).

[EDIT]: added some screenshots to clarify:
[Test document 1 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSgkF.png)
[Test document 1 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmsL0.png)
[Test document 2 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe8Wk.png)
[Test document 2 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNevb.png)
It seems like on 18.04 text is a little bit wider: shrinking it by 0.1 inches takes it back in one single line in both documents.

[EDIT2]: please note that the same documents opened on some windows systems are rendered like in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following command:

```
echo 'FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35 cff:no-stem-darkening=1 autofitter:warping=1"' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/fix-freetype.sh
```

After that logout, and login again to check if its better.

This can be due to freetype interpreter being changed from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/8gqrjn/ubuntu_1804_font_rendering_how_to_make_fonts_look/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, althought I tried your solution but it makes no difference.